# how to resolve this error Websocket connection error Django Nginx

Tags: javascript, django, nginx, websocket

I am unable to make websocket connection with javascript in my django project, currently hosted with nginx. I tried to put the port 8000, 443 and 0 and it didn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w3tj.png)

I need the connection to work

Comment: What error do you have while connecting?

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/index/' failed:

Comment: You need to use wss  instead of ws for deployment . change the url to : wss://yourdomainname.com/